# Create table within table in HTML

Tags: html

Below shows my `HTML` code & it's result.

```
<html>
<body>
   <table width="75%">
      <td>
         <table width="99%" border="4">
            <tr>
               <th>NAME</th>
               <th>AGE</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Dilantha</td>
               <td>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Chamal</td>
               <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Rose</td>
               <td>20</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
      <td>
         <table width="99%" border="4">
            <tr>
               <th>NAME</th>
               <th>YEAR</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Jhon</td>
               <td>2010</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

But I need to show below result. Please help me to complete my `HTML` code. 
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: both are same image..?expected image..?

Comment: he need alignment dude...

Comment: the content on the images are same. but appearance are different.

Comment: I used alignment. but it's not successful.

Comment: Not sure if you've noticed but, John*

Comment: You can see my code in answer area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are expecting the following one right?

[image]

```
<html>
<body>

<table width="75%"> 
<td> 
      <table width="99%" border="4"> 
      <tr><th > NAME </th>
          <th > AGE</th>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
          <td>Dilantha</td>
          <td>30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Chamal</td>
          <td>25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Rose</td>
          <td>20</td>
      </tr>
      </table> 
</td> 


<td style="vertical-align:top"> 
      <table width="99%" border="4"> 
      <tr><th > NAME </th> 
          <th>YEAR</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jhon</td>
          <td>2010</td>
      </tr>

      </table> 
</td> 
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/UEjL2/)**

```
<td style='vertical-align: top;'>
```